# How to draw a continuous curved line from 3 given points at a time

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, bezier, continuous, spline

I am trying to draw a continuous curved line in flash.  There are many methods but none of the ones I have found so far quite fit my requirements.  First of all, **I want to use the flash graphic api's curveTo() method.**  ***I DO NOT want to [simulate a curve with hundreds of calls to lineTo() per curved line segment](http://www.cartogrammar.com/blog/actionscript-curves-update/).***  It is my experience and understanding that line segments are processor heavy.  Flash's quadratic bezier curve should take less CPU power.  Please challenge this assumption if you think I am wrong.

I also do not want to use a pre-made method that takes the entire line as an argument (eg mx.charts.chartClasses.GraphicsUtilities.drawPolyline()).
The reason is that I will need to modify the logic eventually to add decorations to the line I am drawing, so I need something I understand at its lowest level.

I have currently created a method that will draw a curve given 3 points, [using the mid-point method found here](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/05/drawing_curved_.html).

Here is a picture:

[image: A continuous curved line using the actual points as control points]

The problem is that the lines do not actually curve through the "real" points of the line (the gray circles).  Is there a way using the power of math that I can adjust the control point so that the curve will actually pass through the "real" point?  Given only the current point and its prev/next point as arguments?  The code to duplicate the above picture follows.  It would be great if I could modify it to meet this requirement (note the exception for first and last point).

```
package {
  import flash.display.Shape;
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.display.Stage;
  import flash.geom.Point;

  [SWF(width="200",height="200")]
  public class TestCurves extends Sprite {
    public function TestCurves() {
      stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
      var points:Array = [
        new Point(10, 10), 
        new Point(80, 80), 
        new Point(80, 160), 
        new Point(20, 160), 
        new Point(20, 200),
        new Point(200, 100)
      ];

      graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFF0000);

      var point:Point = points[0];
      var nextPoint:Point = points[1];

      SplineMethod.drawSpline(graphics, point, null, nextPoint);

      var prevPoint:Point = point;

      var n:int = points.length;
      var i:int;
      for (i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
        point = nextPoint;
        nextPoint = points[i]; //will eval to null when i == n

        SplineMethod.drawSpline(graphics, point, prevPoint, nextPoint);

        prevPoint = point;
      }

      //straight lines and vertices for comparison
      graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xC0C0C0, 0.5);
      graphics.drawCircle(points[0].x, points[0].y, 4);
      for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        graphics.moveTo(points[i - 1].x, points[i - 1].y);
        graphics.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        graphics.drawCircle(points[i].x, points[i].y, 4);
      }

    }
  }
}
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.geom.Point;

internal class SplineMethod {
  public static function drawSpline(target:Graphics, p:Point, prev:Point=null, next:Point=null):void {
    if (!prev && !next) {
      return; //cannot draw a 1-dimensional line, ie a line requires at least two points
    }

    var mPrev:Point; //mid-point of the previous point and the target point
    var mNext:Point; //mid-point of the next point and the target point

    if (prev) {
      mPrev = new Point((p.x + prev.x) / 2, (p.y + prev.y) / 2);
    }
    if (next) {
      mNext = new Point((p.x + next.x) / 2, (p.y + next.y) / 2);
      if (!prev) {
        //This is the first line point, only draw to the next point's mid-point
        target.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        target.lineTo(mNext.x, mNext.y);
        return;
      }
    } else {
      //This is the last line point, finish drawing from the previous mid-point
      target.moveTo(mPrev.x, mPrev.y);
      target.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
      return;
    }
    //draw from mid-point to mid-point with the target point being the control point.
    //Note, the line will unfortunately not pass through the actual vertex... I want to solve this
    target.moveTo(mPrev.x, mPrev.y);
    target.curveTo(p.x, p.y, mNext.x, mNext.y);
  }
}
```

Later I will be adding arrows and things to the draw method.

Comment: Ok, to get the desired effect, it is starting to look like I may need at least 4 points at any given time for my draw method.  Correct me if I am wrong.  So far, I am just using mid-point calculations; no trig yet.

Comment: There is a spline drawing package for flex: http://www.degrafa.org/docs/

Comment: +1 for the lucid writing style !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the Catmull-Rom spline suggestion is a good one but not *exactly* what I am looking for.
The example from the link provided was a good starting point, but a bit inflexible.  I have taken it and modified my original source code to use it.  I am posting this as an answer because I think it is more modular and easier to understand than Zevan's blog post (no offense Zevan!).  The following code will display the following image:

[image: Spline image with 5 sub-segments per line segment]

Here is the code:

```
    package {
        import flash.display.Shape;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.display.Stage;
        import flash.geom.Point;

        [SWF(width="300",height="300")]
        public class TestCurves extends Sprite {
            public function TestCurves() {
                stage.scaleMode = "noScale";

                //draw a helpful grid
                graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xC0C0C0, 0.5);
                for (var x:int = 0; x <= 300; x += 10) {
                    graphics.moveTo(x, 0);
                    graphics.lineTo(x, 300);
                    graphics.moveTo(0, x);
                    graphics.lineTo(300, x);
                }

                var points:Array = [
                    new Point(40, 20), 
                    new Point(120, 80), 
                    new Point(120, 160), 
                    new Point(60, 160), 
                    new Point(60, 200), 
                    new Point(240, 150), 
                    new Point(230, 220), 
                    new Point(230, 280)
                ];

                SplineMethod.setResolution(5);

                graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xF00000);
                graphics.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

                var n:int = points.length;
                var i:int;

                for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    SplineMethod.drawSpline(
                        graphics, 
                        points[i], //segment start
                        points[i + 1], //segment end
                        points[i - 1], //previous point (may be null)
                        points[i + 2] //next point (may be null)
                    );
                }

                //straight lines and vertices for comparison
                graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x808080, 0.5);
                graphics.drawCircle(points[0].x, points[0].y, 4);
                for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                    graphics.moveTo(points[i - 1].x, points[i - 1].y);
                    graphics.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
                    graphics.drawCircle(points[i].x, points[i].y, 4);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    internal class SplineMethod {

        //default setting will just draw a straight line
        private static var hermiteValues:Array = [0, 0, 1, 0];

        public static function setResolution(value:int):void {
            var resolution:Number = 1 / value;
            hermiteValues = [];
            for (var t:Number = resolution; t <= 1; t += resolution) {
                var h00:Number = (1 + 2 * t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t);
                var h10:Number = t  * (1 - t) * (1 - t);
                var h01:Number = t * t * (3 - 2 * t);
                var h11:Number = t * t * (t - 1);
                hermiteValues.push(h00, h10, h01, h11);
            }
        }

        public static function drawSpline(target:Graphics, segmentStart:Point, segmentEnd:Point, prevSegmentEnd:Point=null, nextSegmentStart:Point=null):void {
            if (!prevSegmentEnd) {
                prevSegmentEnd = segmentStart;
            }
            if (!nextSegmentStart) {
                nextSegmentStart = segmentEnd;
            }

            var m1:Point = new Point((segmentEnd.x - prevSegmentEnd.x) / 2, (segmentEnd.y - prevSegmentEnd.y) / 2);
            var m2:Point = new Point((nextSegmentStart.x - segmentStart.x) / 2, (nextSegmentStart.y - segmentStart.y) / 2);

            var n:int = hermiteValues.length;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i += 4) {
                var h00:Number = hermiteValues[i];
                var h10:Number = hermiteValues[i + 1];
                var h01:Number = hermiteValues[i + 2];
                var h11:Number = hermiteValues[i + 3];

                var px:Number = h00 * segmentStart.x + h10 * m1.x + h01 * segmentEnd.x + h11 * m2.x;
                var py:Number = h00 * segmentStart.y + h10 * m1.y + h01 * segmentEnd.y + h11 * m2.y;

                target.lineTo(px, py);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is *not* a perfect solution.  But unfortunately, I cannot piece together how to accomplish what I want using curveTo().  Note that **[GraphicsUtilities.drawPolyLine()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/chartClasses/GraphicsUtilities.html#drawPolyLine%28%29)** *does* accomplish what I am attempting to do--the problem there is that it is inflexible and I cannot parse the code (more importantly, it doesn't appear to properly draw acute angles--correct me if I am wrong).  If anyone can provide any insight, please post.  For now, the above is my answer.

Comment: Note: a performance increase might be gained from using Vector instead of Array for the Hermite Function values--very important for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for a Catmull-Rom spline. I've googled an AS3 implementation for you but haven't tried it so use at your own discretion:

http://actionsnippet.com/?p=1031

Comment: that's my blog post - so I can confirm that the method on that page should work +1 you just need to replace the pixel drawing code with a graphics class lineTo/moveTo and you should be good to go

Comment: Very nice.  But if I understand it correctly, it fails one of my conditions.  Which is that I not draw multiple straight line segments to simulate a curve.  If I have a performance problem, the only solution would be to lower the curve resolution which would make it more like a series of straight lines.  That is why I need to draw curves with flash's curveTo() method.

Comment: PS, don't think that I am ungrateful.  I really like the method.  But for my current problem I am doubtful that it is a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

I code this, I think it may help:

SWF: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2283327/stackoverflow/SplineTest.swf

Code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2283327/stackoverflow/SplineTest.as

I left a lot of comments on the code. I wish it helps!

Here is the theory behind the code:

[image]

A and C are the first and last point, B is the "control point" in AS3 you can draw the curve like this:

```
graphics.moveTo(A.x, A.y);
graphics.curveTo(B.x, B.y, C.x, C.y);
```

Now, D is the mid-point of the vector AC. And the mid-point of DB is the mid-point of the curve. Now what I did in the code was to move B exactly to D+DB*2 so, if you draw the curve using that point as control point, the mid-point of the curve will be B.

PS: Sorry for my poor Enlgish

Comment: Thanks, but this does not simulate a spline over several arbitrary points.  Please refer to GraphicsUtilities.drawPolyLine() for an example of what I am trying to accomplish.